# How to check if memory usage goes above a certain number?

Tags: macos, memory

I have Dashlane installed, which makes it so that all passwords in my browser get typed automatically. It's actually really useful, except for a single flaw: *it leaks so much memory*. Seriously. After a couple days of running it, it'll have taken over nearly 3 GB of memory and slow down the whole computer.

I'm trying to make a program where it checks Dashlane's memory usage every once in a while and force quits it once it reaches, say, 1 GB.

How can I automatically check if the memory usage of a program goes above a certain number?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some linux knowledge, your question can be rephrased to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process

Add a process memory check to a scheduled task that runs every x hours/minutes. If it exceeds a number kill the process.

Although, if you are confident the issue is with the application you are using, I would take it to their support team, or change the software with a better one.